# POST REQUEST PYTHON does not change the default date in the response

Tags: python, forms, date, post, python-requests

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QcqJ.png)I am trying to post a form data at the https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/ptf.xhtml and i get a response but not with the proper date i post. 
Here is the code i use:

```
import requests.sessions
url = "https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/ptf.xhtml"
aaa = {"j_idt202": "j_idt202",
"j_idt202:date1_input": "15.04.2020",
"j_idt202:date2_input": "17.04.2020",
"j_idt202:goster": "",
"j_idt202:dt_rppDD": "24",
"javax.faces.ViewState": "-4553737376077641878:8530200118323030971"}
bbb = {"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Content-Length": "192",
"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
"Cookie": "JSESSIONID=pRJV7cTKKZBG7umanw-d7LLA5dTvfTd52EDzotlR.prd-transparency-n40; TS015dca6c=01cbc7c0b2c35901079ad1afda5dd13dad6a6f5cc4fcaa1cb200890b1e0401d54b571361e1ceea05c8afd884fc986fa67b08b13d13f8c60c97fff85d2e811da2a543cdf9f8; _ga=GA1.3.1509483381.1584105112; _gid=GA1.3.986020094.1587121047; TS01f69930=01cbc7c0b2ab45c0fe95c9305e91aa235e908d80dec19f4d76119e4e3058ae32aac517c2048199e58051222727e2fe312518660537; _gat=1",
"Host": "seffaflik.epias.com.tr",
"Origin": "https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr",
"Referer": "https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/ptf.xhtml",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.post(url, data= json.dumps(aaa), headers = bbb)
print(r.text)
```

I post the 15.04.2020 and 17.04.2020 but the response contains the current date, which is the default.
Does anyone have an idea on that???

Comment: Which date in the response.html you're referring to?

Comment: @RafalS in the response html contains --> var data=[{"date":"19-04-2020 00:00","price":228.2,"priceUsd":33.01,"priceEur":30.46}... instead of 15.04.2020

Comment: It seems like it's not recognizing your date filters and using the current date as default. You may want to look into the API on how you should specify the dates. Sadly, I don't speak Turkish to look into it

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 i don't speak Turkish either. What do you mean by look into the API ? What exactly should i do?

Comment: How do you know what params to pass in to get your desired result? Are you using any documentation from that site?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 i go to Network and i parameterize the FORM DATA section in the format, it is already filled out.

Comment: I added a picture for what exactly i mean

Comment: on a similar webpage i just changed the parameters in form data section and it worked.

Comment: @Nelman  see my answer and let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 0):

> on a similar webpage I just changed the parameters in the form data section and it worked.

The above would have worked if the data that you are fetching is simple a static data, i.e. there's no Js code execution involved to retrieve the data. Note that, `request` module simply makes an HTTP request to the defined url with the given headers and parameters and simply responds with whatever the server yields.

To do what you want, it is only achievable using web APIs, such that you define what you want in filters and the server responds with appropriate data you requested([example here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/)). This [site](https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/piyasalar/gop/ptf.xhtml) unfortunately doesn't have any. A good alternative would be to explore on `Headless Web Automation` where a browser instance would start and fetch the data that you request. You can research more on this if you like.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But, how did you find out that it does not have any ?
I have created an automation with selenium, however it is very slow and not so credible.

Comment: The only related site that comes up is [this](https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/technical/tr/) which doesn't look like what i am looking for. As it's in a foreign language, I also find it hard to interpret meanings even after performing google translation.

Comment: https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/technical/en/  is in english

Comment: You can also work on why the selenium is slow. In my experience I find the speed okay. Are you using headless?

Comment: When I use headless, it does not get the right date i submit  or it does not get any.
It only works without headless and with no credibility again. Can i send you my script to give me your opinion?

Comment: Is this https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/technical/en/#_gop_kesinlesmemis_ptf_rest_servisi the one we need?? I will not be able to run selenium since i have different driver version atm

Comment: 2.54. DayAheadMCP   is what we need.

Comment: Great. If `2.54` is what you want then what's going wrong? I cant further test this since it requires me to subscribe according to their steps [here](https://seffaflik.epias.com.tr/transparency/technical/en/#_transparency_postman_requests). If you have the credentials then follow the steps on the link above and it should work

Comment: The problem is that i do not have the credentials either.

Comment: Then I guess it's not possible then. You would have to stick with selenium and optimize it for faster execution. If this answer has helped then feel free to accept by clicking the tick sign. Thanks

Comment: Here's something incase it helps https://seleniumjava.com/2015/12/12/how-to-make-selenium-webdriver-scripts-faster/